# Regex for handling values with surrounding characters?

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0

I would like to convert values in a string with surrounding `||` symbols. For example, `||more info||` would have to be changed to `<a href="#">more info</a>`. How do I do this while leaving the text in the middle ("more info" can be anything else)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably the simplest way to do what you want:

```
var pattern = @"\|\|(.+?)\|\|";
var replacement = @"<a href=""#"">$1</a>";
var input = "you can get ||more info|| here";

var result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement);
Console.WriteLine (result);
```